# What's the meaning and origin of the phrase 'Vyasocchishtam jagat sarvam'?

Tags: sanskrit, vyasa

What's the origin of the phrase **Vyasocchishtam jagat sarvam**?

I've heard different meanings of the phrase some of which are:

- There is nothing under the Sun that Vyasa has not touched upon.
- Whatever anyone speaks/writes is something already uttered/written by Vyasa

Comment: In my opinion, both mean the same thing. Vyasa had touched upon all disciplines of knowledge. Just like we use the term 'Jack of all trades', he is considered 'Master of all trades'. Also, the seats of the revered teachers in many Indian disciplines is knows as Vyasa Peeth.

Comment: I think it is  saying about VedaVyasa like "अष्टवर्षेचतुर्वेदी, द्वादशेसर्वशास्त्रवित्
षोडशेकृतवान्भाष्यम्द्वात्रिंशेमुनिरभ्यगात्" for Adi Shankaracharya.